# Which regression model would you choose?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model-selection, model

Which regression model would you choose to model the following flood damage data? The variables are x1=water height, x2=dike height and x3=flood damage. The following plot shows how the flood damages depend on the water height, the zcolor is the overtopping of the water (x1-x2).
[image]

You can see two linear lines, in fact, if you zoom into the lower one you would find that this is not a linear relationship as it seems like from this perspective. Apparently the overtopping variable splits the dataset (below or above zero).

Flood damage plotted over the dike height looks like this:
[image]

and here is damage over overtopping:
[image]

Due to the next worksteps I need one regressor that models the flood damages of this dataset that I can later use to do an integration to determine the annual flood damages. I would like to have the following monotone constraint fulfilled: increased water height leads to equal or higher flood damages and an increased dike height leads to equal or lower flood damages.

I concluded that a linear model (or other nonlinear regressions) is not suitable as I have two lines in the first plot and no linear relationship in the second. I thought that a random forest or regression tree would be good to handle this data. I tried to setup a random forest with lightGBM to add the monotone constraints, but unfortunately did not succeed, yet. How would you model this dataset?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated SE! I would potentially recommend employing some form of nonparametric smoothing, e.g. [Local Regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) , [Kernel Regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) , to your data sets as this may assist in determining the type of relationship in a less subjective way than just viewing the scatter plots. I'm unsure what language you are programming in, but I think most common languages used for statistical analysis (R, Python, etc.) should have packages ready available for this! :)

Comment: How is damage measured? Also, there seem to be subpopulations that respond differently to overflooding - was this all measured at the same spot, or do you have more covariates, like type of land behond the deik? You might get a stronger prediction if there are meaningful covariates in your data

Comment: Regression splines can handle the nonlinearities.

Comment: thank you all for the input! I use Julia or Python and will have a look at nonparametric smoothing with local regression and kernel regression. The damage is measured in monetary units after pre-processing the pixel wise inundation depths from a hydrodynamic model and estimating building values in each pixel. The hydrodynamic model is for one specific place, hence the variables x1 and x2 is all I got.

Comment: I have one more question, hopefully I can explain what I mean... can nonparametric smoothing and/or regression splines handle data that needs "more than one function"? From what I've seen, nonparametric smoothing and regression splines model one nonlinear function, like a polynomial. But in my example, I cannot see this "one function", rather, I see several functions in one plot, depending on the amount of overtopping or dike height.

Comment: If I'm getting what you mean, I think nonparametric smoothing and splines should be able to what you want since although you will get a specific function from these methods (a set of inputs/outputs or a function that can be evaluated at inputs), due to the nature of the method, it will be a combination of various other functions that are pieced together which in the case of polynomial splines would tend to be polynomials giving you a more "complex" final function based on the fitting parameters. If you are instead wanting to account for the impact that varying the x-axis would have on the...

Comment: ... _distribution_ of the damage, you may then want to look into generating a probabilistic prediction for the damage conditional on the x-axis variable :)

Comment: thank you for your answers, I really appreciate it :) Can I please ask one more clarification question to doublecheck that we are talking about the same thing? I mean that all the applications I found in the internet model one continious function over one variable, e.g. https://docs.juliahub.com/Loess/TysgR/0.5.2/. In my case, however, I see at least two lines in the first picture and not one single continous function. So can these methods create sth like "if overtopping is >0 follow this function, else use this function"?

Comment: No problem! I'm not familiar with the implementation of Loess in Julia, but I think that most implementations of LOESS/LOWESS tend to attempt to fit a smooth line/curve to the data in some fashion by considering a weighted average of neighboring points as opposed to creating an explicit boolean statement for the function, although this could potentially be implicitly reflected when fitting the model. If you're explicitly wanting to include boolean statements in your model, you may want to look at something like either a decision tree if you need to see the exact logic behind the model or ...

Comment: ... or a random forest if you still want to employ this boolean modeling in your application, but have less of a necessity for direct interpretability. I'm not too familiar with the following concept, but [Segmented Regression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_regression) may also be something to look into as it seems to do what I think you're wanting (explicitly different functions for different partitions of the regressors, etc).

Comment: great, thank you for this overview and your thoughts in this!

Comment: Of course, no problem! :) Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: Also, just a note that you can @ people that have responded to the comments of a post with @(insert name here) without the parentheses so that it will notify them that you've commented :) otherwise, they may not see it as to my knowledge, commenting only notifies the poster unless @'s are used.

Comment: I see, thank you @QMath :)

Comment: of course, no problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a lot of damage = 0 in your dataset, meaning it is 0-inflated. I would first run 2 binomial GLMs on presence/absence of damage according to :

- x1 * x2 (interaction between water height and dike height)
- x1-x2 (overtopping)

This would tell you about the likelihood of damage occurring according to the value of these variables. It will probably show you whether it is more relevant to use x1 and x2 further, or to stick with x1-x2. Then I would take a decision from here.
I would say that there is no point having x1, x2 and x1-x2 in the same model, since x1-x2 will be colinear with x1 and x2.

Comment: thank you for your input! I agree that x1,x2 and x1-x2 in one linear model violate the colinearity assumption. But the damage is in fact never zero in the data, it only looks like this due to the scaling of the y axis. The damage is either very high (if x1-x2 > 130 cm) or quite low (if x1-x2 <130). Does this already answer your question how the damages behave with respect to x1 and x2?

Comment: Then I would say even when the damage is not 0, there is a clear binomial distribution of the response variable, as you say very high or quite low. I think I would need to know what your question is. Are you interested in properly detecting the threshold which determines whether the damage is going to be very high or quite low, which you already know (very high if x1-x2 > 130 cm) ?

Comment: I would like to find a regressor that can predict the flood damage, e.g. f(x1,x2). I am not looking for a classification whether there will be high or low flood damage, instead, I am interested in the exact height of the flood damage. As the first and third picture does not exhibit one clear function, but rather two or more functions next to each other, I am a bit lost how to approach this regression task. Or are you suggesting to nest two regressions after another, e.g. first the bonimal high or low and then a second regression for the exact height?

Comment: I think I would first do presence/absence of damage, then exclude the "low damage" category and analyze the amount of damage within the high damage cases.

Comment: thank you for your idea! I actually did something similar, but then my final integration over x1 violated the monotone assumptios of the model behaviour. But maybe in combination with splines or local regression the results will be better